# How to substitute " for" loop and if/ else if statements? Extracting data form data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am working in R on data frame consisting of time and precipitation data (over 3 000 000 values, measured every minute)

I would like to extract all "precipitation episodes", which are actually all moments when it was raining (dp != 0, but also including possible break in raining but no longer then "a" of the next measurements)

I would like all episodes to be stored in the new data frame with additional column with the number of each of them. First rain - 1, Second - 2....

The example of "precipitation episode":

```
time <- c("2013-01-01 11:39:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:40:00", "2013-01-01 11:41:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:42:00","2013-01-01 11:43:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:44:00","2013-01-01 11:45:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:46:00","2013-01-01 11:47:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:48:00","2013-01-01 11:49:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:50:00","2013-01-01 11:51:00",
        "2013-01-01 11:52:00","2013-01-01 11:53:00")

time <- as.POSIXct(time , origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")

p<- c(1.565, 1.565, 1.658, 1.795, 1.795, 1.795, 1.896, 1.896, 2.985, 2.985, 
      2.985, 2.985, 3.5, 3.7, 3.85)

df <- data.frame(time, p)   
dp <- diff(df$p)

df$dp<- c(dp,0)
```

I created a function using for loop and (a lot of) if conditions, which I hope represents well my intentions. Its currently not working well - still looking for the reason why.

```
rain.episodes<- function(x) {
  a<- 300
  episode.number <- 1
  rain <- reja.clean[1,] #just for column names

  for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {

    if (x[i,"dp"] >0) {
        rain[i,]<- x[i,]
        rain[i, "episode.number"]<- episode.number
        a<-0

    } else if (x[i,"dp"] ==0 & a<300) {
        rain[i,]<- x[i,]
        rain[i, "episode.number"]<- episode.number
        a<-a+1

    } else if (a==301) {
        episode.number<-episode.number+1

    } else{
          a<-a+1
    }
  }
  return(rain)
}
```

Is there any way to create a function helping me with that issue, with the same output as the one I pasted, but using different (better) method?

I would also like to know why my function doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please add your expected output as well?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @AleksandraN , welcome to SO! Your desired output is equal (except for one column, that seems a 1 constant: I imagine that is not, but without a simpler explaination, it seems it) to your input data. Could you specify more your question - desired output?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its a little bit hard to explain on the small example, but i have over 3000000 measurements of time and p (precipitation/rainfall)  and the column dp which shows if it was raining or not. 

It happens that dp ==0 for 4 days, then its raining so dp!= 0 and then it can be 0 for lets say 1h and change again. 

I would like to find and collect all "episodes" when dp!= 0, giving each of them different number in the additional column (during this episode the rain can stop for 1h but it will still be the same rain)

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo) # for `na.locf`
library(data.table) # for Step 2
```

Step 1: Identify the rainy/non-rainy episodes: TRUE/FALSE

```
df_new <- df[-1,] %>% #remove the first non-rainy observation to suit `na.locf`**
  arrange(time) %>%
  # create ind_hour to keep the time when it rained
  mutate(ind_hour = ifelse (dp != 0, format(as.POSIXct(time) ,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), NA)) %>%
  # when it did not rain (i.e. ind_hour is NA), add an extra hour to the last known time when it rained (use na.locf to get the last time when it rained)
  mutate(ind_hour_complete = ifelse(is.na(ind_hour), (na.locf(as.POSIXct(ind_hour, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")) + hours(1)), time)) %>%
  # if `time` is lower or equal to the `ind_hour_complete`, then we are looking at the same episode
  mutate(same_episode = time <= ind_hour_complete) %>%
  select(-ind_hour, -ind_hour_complete)
```

**Note: within a vector that starts by an `NA`, `na.locf` will remove it and the resulting vector will have length `(n-1)`. Here, the results would shift up one row. You may try the code without removing the first row from `df` to see what I mean. If needed, you may add back this first row  at the very end, with an `ep_number` equal to `max(df_new$ep_number) + 1` (to ensure the `ep_number` is unique). I have removed it completely because you do not seem to need it (according to your expected output).

Step 2: Add indexes for the identified episodes: ep_number

```
df_new <- setDT(df_new)[, ep_number:= rleid(same_episode)]
```

Comment: Thank you! When i tried to apply your solution on a test data frame, the error occured: "cannot arrange column of class 'function' at position 1" and later same more of different ones. I'm not sure though if this approach would work the way i would like to.  I tried to explain my desired solution using for loop and if statements (attached in my edited post). It doesnt actually work properly yet, but I think it shows my intentions. I know that I can't use this kind of functions on such big dataset, so I hope i will find better idea ;)